# Tableview controller how to add edit button to rearrange the rows IOS Swift 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

please find code below, I need an edit button at the top of my tableviewcontroller view, which can rearrange or delete the rows. Any help will be appreciated. I found an in built function to delete individual row but I specifically need an edit button.

```
    import UIKit

    class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
        var sports:[Sport] = []
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            loadData()
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
            // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

            // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
            // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
        }
        func loadData(){




            if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "plist"){
                if let tempDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path){
                    let tempArray = (tempDict.valueForKey("sports") as! NSArray) as Array
                    for dict in tempArray {

                        let sportName = dict["sportName"]! as! String

                        let numberOfPlayers = dict["numberOfPlayers"]! as! String

                        let countryOfOrigin = dict["countryOfOrigin"]! as! String


                        let p = Sport(sportName: sportName, numberOfPlayers:numberOfPlayers, countryOfOrigin:countryOfOrigin)
                        sports.append(p)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        // MARK: - Table view data source

        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
            return sports.count
        }


        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            var sport = sports[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.text = sport.getSportName()
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = sport.getCountryOfOrigin()

            // Configure the cell...

            return cell
        }


        /*
        // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
            // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
            return true
        }
        */

        /*
        // Override to support editing the table view.
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .Delete {
                // Delete the row from the data source
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
                // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
            }    
        }
        */

        /*
        // Override to support rearranging the table view.
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        }
        */

        /*
        // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
            // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
            return true
        }
        */

        /*
        // MARK: - Navigation

        // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        }
        */
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let sport = sports[indexPath.row]
            let detailVC = SportsDetailVC(style: .Grouped)
    //        detailVC.title = park.title
            detailVC.sport = sport
    //        detailVC.zoomDelegate = mapVC
            navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)

        }

    }


import UIKit

class SportsDetailVC: UITableViewController {
    var sport:Sport!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier")
        if cell == nil{
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier:"resuseIdentifier")
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.text = sport.getNumberOfPlayers()
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell!
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Use the `editButtonItem()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated code contains the following comments:

```
// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

Uncomment the second line:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

You may also need to implement some of the other delegate functions for the functionality to work:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
```

For example the little bars on the right the you tap/hold in order to reorder items will not be available unless you implement the appropriate delegate methods.

Comment: Excellent! It may be helpful to others to know this solved your problem (accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the tutorial in the link below. It contains a full answer for your problem. Its base on swift 2.0

[How to delete & reorder rows uitableview in iOS Swift](http://blog.apoorvmote.com/delete-reorder-rows-uitableview-ios-swift/)